# CentOS7: remove nvidia-x11-drv-340xx wants to uninstall the whole xorg

Tags: centos, xorg, gnome, yum, nvidia

I need VNC xorg access to a headless server. So I installed, like I did for a twin one, Gnome and all the stuff. By mistake I had *elrepo* repository enabled, and when installing gnome I had it installed with *nvidia-x11-drv-340xx* package. This prevents me from accessing the Gnome session because it fails detecting accelerated graphics. This is what I found in logs:

```
Thu Nov 19 07:10:04 2015
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on all interface(s), port 5901
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":1".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":1".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":1".
gnome-session-is-accelerated: No hardware 3D support.
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":1".
gnome-session-check-accelerated: Helper exited with code 256

Thu Nov 19 07:10:11 2015
 Connections: accepted: 10.22.33.6::47408
 SConnection: Client needs protocol version 3.8
 SConnection: Client requests security type VncAuth(2)
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":1".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":1".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":1".
gnome-session-is-accelerated: No hardware 3D support.
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":1".
gnome-session-check-accelerated: Helper exited with code 256

** (process:16465): WARNING **: software acceleration check failed: Child process exited with code 1
```

So I try to remove `kmod-nvidia-340xx-340.93-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64` and `nvidia-x11-drv-340xx-340.93-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64`, but when I do `yum remove kmod-nvidia-340xx-340.93-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 nvidia-x11-drv-340xx-340.93-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64` it wants to remove the **whole xorg**!

I also found that `/usr/lib64/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so` is pointing to nvidia libs (via `ldd`). But this package is owned by `xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.15.0-33.el7_1.x86_64`, and even if I reinstall it the situation remains unchanged.

How can I safely remove those nvidia packages and run xorg without accelerated drivers?

**UPDATE**
Here's the list of installed packages on the working server, and the diff of `xorg|x11` rpms between the two:

```
abrt-addon-xorg-2.1.11-22.el7.centos.0.1.x86_64
dbus-x11-1.6.12-11.el7.x86_64
pulseaudio-module-x11-3.0-30.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-apps-7.7-6.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-drivers-7.7-6.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-ati-7.4.0-1.20140918git56c7fb8.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-dummy-0.3.6-15.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-evdev-2.8.2-5.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-fbdev-0.4.3-15.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-intel-2.99.916-5.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-modesetting-0.8.0-13.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-nouveau-1.0.10-5.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-qxl-0.1.1-12.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-synaptics-1.7.1-13.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-v4l-0.2.0-35.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-vesa-2.3.2-14.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-vmmouse-13.0.0-10.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-vmware-13.0.2-1.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-void-1.4.0-23.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-drv-wacom-0.23.0-6.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-fonts-Type1-7.5-9.el7.noarch
xorg-x11-font-utils-7.5-18.1.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-glamor-0.6.0-2.20140918git347ef4f.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-server-common-1.15.0-33.el7_1.x86_64
xorg-x11-server-utils-7.7-4.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.15.0-33.el7_1.x86_64
xorg-x11-utils-7.5-13.1.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-xauth-1.0.7-6.1.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-xinit-1.3.2-14.el7.x86_64
xorg-x11-xkb-utils-7.7-9.1.el7.x86_64
```

and the diff:

```
diff -Naur srv01s srv02s 
--- srv01s  2015-11-23 08:38:02.993066495 +0100
+++ srv02s  2015-11-23 08:38:02.569057434 +0100
@@ -1,7 +1,6 @@

 abrt-addon-xorg-2.1.11-22.el7.centos.0.1.x86_64
 dbus-x11-1.6.12-11.el7.x86_64
-nvidia-x11-drv-340xx-340.93-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64
 pulseaudio-module-x11-3.0-30.el7.x86_64
 xorg-x11-apps-7.7-6.el7.x86_64
 xorg-x11-drivers-7.7-6.el7.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

Install first an alternative package for the same function. I suspect it wants to remove the whole xorg because it has no alternatives to remain.

Comment: indeed it could be, but I updated the post above with the list of packages and the diff between the two servers, apparently there's only the nvidia driver as difference between the two